Was there an episode with Goku having wings?
I remember there being a scene or outro(?) where Goku was shown with a halo or wings.
Are there any episodes or a movie showing Goku with wings and a halo?

It's the cover panel of Dragon Ball manga chapter 417 ("The Grand Finale"), which marks the beginning of the aftermath of Cell's arc. See for instance: https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Finale
We see Goku with angel-like wings and King Kai with insect-like wings, both sporting halos. The scene has never taken place in-world.
Added: Upon further research, the panel is also featured in We Were Angels ( https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/We_Were_Angels ), which is an ending theme for anime Dragon Ball Z episodes 200-291. See for instance here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U5u5n5qsLSE
